# How to create a real simple json server?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

i'm looking a way to create a simple json server which would only get some data and work with them. Without a deep schemas and etc.

All posted answers in web is to deep, difficult, or using deprecated methods/modules :(

All what i need that is:

Client:

```
requests.post('http://localhost:80108', json={'data':'test'})
```

Server:

```
....
....
....
data = json.loads(rcv_data)
if data['data'] == 'test':
    print('Simple test')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSON is not the important part here, serializing and deserializing JSON data is done by the standard library `json` module.

What you need is a simple server that accepts requests and calls Python code; there are several small frameworks that would fit the bill, [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) is a good option.

Answer (score 3):

So you basically need to exchange jsons with a server? Have you thought of a simple REST API? You can implement one with [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) or even easier with [Flask-Restful](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html) + standard `json` module.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a simple answer but I'd recommend looking at how to make a [django api app](https://codeburst.io/create-a-django-api-in-under-20-minutes-2a082a60f6f3). It is a good starting point. Then use [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/django/index.htm) to you get you to where you need to be. A previous answer mentioned flask. Flask is very similar to django but I'd recommend django over flask if you plan on building this out as a larger project.

Answer (score 0):

Ty for answers. Flask is that what i was looking for.

Server:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

def post_actions(data):
        return {
            'Action1': func1,
            'Action2': func2,
            'Action3': func3,
            }.get(data['Action'])(data['Data'])

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def indx():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.data:
            rcv_data = json.loads(request.data.decode(encoding='utf-8'))
            rsp = post_actions(rcv_data)
            if rsp:
                return rsp
            else:
                return '200'
        else:
            return '404'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='localhost', port='43560')
```

Client:

```
import requests

data = {'Action': 'Action2',
        'Data': ['MILK', 'BREAD', 'WATER']}

response = request.post('http://localhost:43560/', json=data)
print(response.text)
>>>'200'
```